# SSIS - Convert string value to binary bit value from flat file

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I think this may be a futile effort, but I'm importing a flat file to a table in MS SQL Server.  There's a value `Y` or `N` in the flat which I correspondingly wish to load as of course a 1 or 0 in the corresponding table column.  I don't suppose there is any trick to accomplishing as such?  It's having an incoming value of `Y` then 1, otherwise 0.

Is this possible to do in SSIS?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2924/case-statement-functionality-in-sql-server-integration-services-derived-column-transformation/

Comment: That'll walk you through how to accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Derived Column Transformation in you DataFlow Task with the Following expression

```
[Column] == "Y" ? 1 : 0
```

OR

```
(DT_BOOL)([Column] == "Y" ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: Does that add a new derived column?  Is there a way to simply map an incoming value to an existing column?  What I'm after is that in the input flat file, there is a Y value I want to map to an existing column in SQL Server table, and the column is a bit data type.  Want to map Y to 1, otherwise 0

Comment: @Scott just map the output of derived column